# Json not posting values to PHP

Tags: php, ajax, json, cordova

i'm trying out a simple login form through phonegap, the code is herewith. my problem is that JSON is not passing the values from my phonegap page to the PHP service. Any help is appreciated
Here is my script:

```
 $('form').submit(function(){
    //var postData = $(this).serialize();
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data:JSON.stringify({username:"username",password:"password"}),
        ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'http://10.0.2.2:81/comment.php',
        success: function(response){
             alert ("response"); 
                        if (response) { 
                            alert("you're logged in");
                            }
                            else {

                            alert("Your login failed");

                        }

        },
        error: function(){

            alert('There was an error with your login');
        }
    });

    return True;
});
```

My PHP page is as follows

```
    <?php 
    header('content-type: application/json');
    header("access-control-allow-origin: *");

    $server = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "comment";

    $con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db($database, $con);

     $username=$_POST["username"]; 
     $password=$_POST["password"]; 
     $sql="SELECT username, password FROM comment WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'"; 
     $result = mysql_query($sql); 
     if (mysql_num_rows($result) < 1)
     { $response =true; }
    else
    { $response =false; 
    }

    mysql_close($con); 
    echo json_encode($response);
     ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    //var postData = $(this).serialize();
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
         data : {username:username, password:password},

        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'http://10.0.2.2:81/comment.php',
        success: function(response){
             alert ("response"); 
                        if (response) { 
                            alert("you're logged in");
                            }
                            else {

                            alert("Your login failed");

                        }

        },
        error: function(){

            alert('There was an error with your login');
        }
    });

    return True;
});
```

Comment: Please don't forget to mention what was error in OP's code and what changes you made it to solve.

Answer (score 0):

you can not get that data straight forward using $_POST varriable.to accept json you need to read from stdin input

```
<?php 
header('content-type: application/json');
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");

$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "comment";

$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($database, $con);
 ////here you need to change
 $request = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $reqRarray = json_decode($request,true);
//////`enter code here`
 $username=$reqRarray["username"]; 
 $password=$reqRarray["password"]; 
 $sql="SELECT username, password FROM comment WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'"; 
 $result = mysql_query($sql); 
 if (mysql_num_rows($result) < 1)
 { $response =true; }
else
{ $response =false; 
}

mysql_close($con); 
echo json_encode($response);
```

?>

I have tested with following javascript code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script  type='text/javascript'>
         $(document).ready(function(){
            //var postData = $(this).serialize();
            var username = 'test';
            var password = 'meu';
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data:JSON.stringify({username:"username",password:"password"}),
                ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'ajax.php',
                success: function(response){
                     alert ("response"); 
                                if (response) { 
                                    alert("you're logged in");
                                    }
                                    else {

                                    alert("Your login failed");

                                }
                },
                error: function(){

                    alert('There was an error with your login');
                }
            });

            return true;
         });
        </script>
</head>
<body></body>
```

and with folling php code:

```
<?php
$request = file_get_contents('php://input');
$reqRarray = json_decode($request,true);
var_dump($reqRarray);
?>
```

and get that output on ajax:

```
array (size=2)  'username' => string 'username' (length=8)  'password' => string 'password' (length=8)
```

Comment: I'm afraid how it will (`file_get_contents('php://input');`) read data from `POST` ajax request?

Comment: actually it will read post json request string.see it sends json request body you need to use file_get_contents('php://input'); to get that json request string.You can not get it using normal $_POST varriable

Comment: Well, Good to know. Thanks. But I never used `php://input`, kind of new to me. I always used `$_POST` and it works well..! :)

Comment: actually file_get_contents('php://input'); is used to read raw post data and json request is raw post data.so everything is fine :)

Comment: Okay, But after reading raw json string again we need to use `json_decode()`. Better to use `$_POST`. Believe me, it works dude. No need to use external function to convert json and all, since example given in OP that ajax will pass individual parameters and *NOT JSON*.

Comment: sometimes request are coming as raw json.what you will you do then?I have seen such many examples.like I see many iphone application send raw json to their api server.what will you do on that case? :D :D

Comment: That never happened to me in last 2 years. I too developed web-services for iPhone, Android. :)

Comment: I don't want to argue with you but it still has application like you need to send some complex data in json with several nested data.I have worked with such application and it is just a new way. there is no way you can tell that what is purely good or bad. in one application one is good in another application 2nd one is good. like it is very complex to send several nested json with simple post request on that case you need to use that. but simpler case $_POST is better and easy to use

Comment: Yeah, Knew it. It wasn't argument though, just a small talk. Sharing is good idea. Thank you! :)

Comment: and I am also working on software development+web development over the last 5 years. That is not a big deal.

Comment: @SabbirAhmedSourove i tried your method, the problem still persists, the data delivered to the php page is still blank..!!

Comment: @SabbirAhmedSourove i dont know where i'm going wrong sir, but your revision is displaying the error: function() alert..!! code block..!!

Comment: I just show that data is sending and fetched perfectly using json format.If you can use firebug or any other request observer you can see what is actually happening.actually you see currently your problem is in other place.like database query,mysql connection.It is not related to json posting.I just only shows json posting works in this way.